# RBAC management in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, acl, laravel-5.3, rbac

I want add a package to Laravel for managing roles and permissions,

I found some packages:

- https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentinel/2.0
- http://docs.toddish.co.uk/verify/laravel-5/
- https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust

But I don't know which one is better!

**My Requirement:**

I have an admin panel and user management system already, now I want add a section for adding user groups so I can create users groups from admin panel and then assign permissions to user groups, and then I can assign users to groups.
And in site I should verify user access.

I want to know can I manage groups and roles with db and from admin panel with these packages?

Comment: try https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust

Comment: @AbuSayem Thanks, do you have any tutorial for integration permissions into database ?

Comment: Read its doc. I think it is well documented

Comment: You should try PHP-Casbin and its Laravel middleware: https://github.com/php-casbin/laravel-authz

Answer (score 0):

I used entrust which is pretty good and scalable role-base access control.

I can give you a quick start :

- Use composer to install.
- Add alias to the `config/app.php`
- Run php artisan `vendor:publish`
- Open your `config/auth.php` and add the following to it:

  `'providers' => [
      'users' => [
          'driver' => 'eloquent',
          'model' => Namespace\Of\Your\User\Model\User::class,
          'table' => 'users',
      ],
  ],`
- If you want to use Middleware and you should use then add :

  `'role' => \Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustRole::class,
   'permission' => \Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustPermission::class,
   'ability' => \Zizaco\Entrust\Middleware\EntrustAbility::class,`
- Set the property values in the config/auth.php. These values will be
  used by entrust to refer to the correct user table and model.
- Generate the Entrust migration:

  `php artisan entrust:migration` Then `php artisan migrate`

Note : Check your migration tables.

Now add models : `Role`, `Permission` for both use `use Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustRole;`

In your `User` Model use `use Zizaco\Entrust\Traits\EntrustUserTrait;`.

And `composer dump-autoload`.

You are good to go.

---

To add roles and permissions, You should have view, A view to add list users in a table along with roles, Like when you edit a user there should be an option for roles in a drop down.

Then for roles there should be permissions like and `admin` have permission to `read,write,delete`. So now you have a view where you are giving permissions to the roles.

Rest is your own logic, Your needs.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to know how can I add roles and permission to database from admin panel, how can I add new group and permissions ? should I add manually to `Role`, `Permission` tables ?